# How to remove outline for Material row header with MatSort in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-material-table

I got an issue after implementing `MatSort` to my Material table. It's showing outline for the header column name when click on it to sort

[image]

Is it possible to disable it? If possible, Please help me on how to do it.

I implemented Material table with sorting as shown in the below link:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code in style.css

```
 .mat-sort-header-button {
    outline: none !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the following:

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-button {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of may-2021 I had to use the following:

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```